# low-level UI library that allows custom text selection mechanics

Tags: linux, python, c++, user-interface, text

I need a GUI or TUI library for linux, that can be used from C, C++ or Python. The library shouldn't give me a repertoir of widgets, but instead allow me to build my own from scratch. I need a scrollable area of uneditable text, on which I can build my own selection mechanics.

Namely, I need to be allowed to select only whole words (so no parts of a word) or subset consisting of whole words that isn't necessarily continuous. I also need to tell what changes in selection happen when I press, move and release a mouse button, none of these sohuld have default behavior. A tool which allows me to locate the offset in the text of the point where my mouse is at, and a tool that allows me to mark individual characters as selected or not selected would be ideal!

I tried GTK library, but it assumes too much and I can't turn off some unneeded features.
What libraries do you suggest?